# Does 'publish-subscribe' messaging pattern require as many queues as there are consumers?

Tags: message-queue, publish-subscribe

Say I need to publish the price to a given stock ticker everytime the price changes, and on the other end there are subscribers (consumers) that need to consume that price.

This is a typical pub-sub pattern (instead of point-to-point). Is it typical to set up N queues if there N consumers, and have the publisher publish the same message to each of the N queues?

I don't see how this can be accomplished with only one queue, as each message will be gone as soon as a single consumer picks it up (which is a point-to-point model)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, message passing communication system require queue per customer.

If customers observe changing event, you need queue per customer.
You publish event to some message broker. Consumers come and create own queue. After than, consumer bind own queue to your event exchange. Only this way every cunsumer reach and proccess every event.

Or

You create one consumer. That consumer consume event and send notification requst to every customer. This way not feasable, because you have to know every customer and their endpoint address for accepting notification. Moreover, you have to handle errors during integration etc. etc.